# Angular routing displaying the same app.component.html

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm currently using Angular version 13.

As stated by the official documentation, routing should be done by creating a component and routing it like this in the app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'first-component', component: 
FirstComponent },
{ path: 'second-component', component: 
SecondComponent },
];
```

but doing so will render my app.comoponent.html file without actually changing anything. I can see that the url changed, but that's about it.
Other newer sources consider doing something like

```
{
path:'mainpage',
loadChildren: () => import('./mainpage/mainpage.module').then(m 
=> m.MainpageModule)
}
```

and, as the solution above, does not work for me. I've also added the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive, (which was actually already added) but nothing changed. What is currently happening? Thanks!

Comment: side note, the last line can be written `loadChildren: async () => (await import('./mainpage/mainpage.module')).MainpageModule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RouterOutlet` Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state so in most cases you'll probably have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive in your app.component.html. This element actually informs Angular to update the application view with the component for the selected route.

Each route in routes array is a JavaScript object which contains two properties. The first property is the path which defines the URL path for the route. The second one is the component which defines the component Angular should use for the corresponding path.

`loadChildren` is a different issue. By default, Angular `NgModules` are eagerly loaded, which means that as soon as the application loads, so does all of the `NgModules`, even if they are not immediately necessary. If you wish to use lazy loading for Angular modules, you can use the `loadChildren` (instead of component like in your first example) in your `AppRoutingModule` routes.

Comment: Ok, perfect explanation, I'm starting to get the gist of it. So actually loadchildren woudl employ lazyloading, which is something that i don't currently want. But basically you're telling me that everything is at is should be right? If i would user the router-outlet + the first routing i SHOULD see my component? If so thanks, my problem is elsewhere :)

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on the matter. I was using the app.component.html as an introduction page, and it would overlap any page i was trying to route. The Routing effectively worked, but it displayed stuff from the app component. Hope to help some beginners! Ty very much again

Comment: Most welcome my friend

Comment: I have accidentally deleted <router-outlet></router-outlet> from app.component.ts and that was the exact reason why every route was simply displaying app component